# WPF How to show a MemoryStream PDF document to a WebBrowser

Tags: database, wpf, pdf, webbrowser-control, memorystream

I cant show a pdf document save it in a database table direcly to a WebBrowser using a MemoryStream.

I have a DataBase with pfd documents saved in a table filed, and I want to show the pdf document saved in a table field over a WebBrowser. I have this code:

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="pdfWebViewer" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,0,439,0"/>
<WebBrowser x:Name="pdfWebViewer2" Grid.Row="1" Margin="425,0,0,0"/>
```

and

```
pdfWebViewer.Navigate(new Uri("about:blank"));
if (_record != null)
{
    _bytes = _record.PDF_DOC; // It's a BLOB Database field ;
    MemoryStream outstream = new MemoryStream(_record.PDF_DOC.ToArray());
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(_path + "borar.pdf", _record.PDF_DOC.ToArray());
    pdfWebViewer.Navigate(_path + "borar.pdf");
    pdfWebViewer2.NavigateToStream(outstream);

}
```

The result is :
[image]

Document on the left is pdfWebViewer and on the right is pdfWebViewer2